# Create zipfile at local and write files from s3

Tags: python, zip, python-zipfile

I am creating a zipfile on my local machine and would like to write files from s3. So far I'm unable to do it. Here's what I have in the mean time.

```
import os
import zipfile
from fs import open_fs

fs = open_fs(os.getenv('s3_sample_folder'))
file_names = file_names() #list of file names

with zipfile.ZipFile('zipfile.zip', mode='w') as zf:
   for file in file_names:
       with fs.open('/'+file, 'rb') as remote_file:
           content = remote_file.read()
           zf.write(content, basename(content))
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `ZipFile.write` method accepts a file name, not file content. You should use the `ZipFile.writestr` method instead to write file content to the zip file:

```
zf.writestr(file, content)
```

Comment: Is it possible to use the `write` method so I can retain the filename?

Comment: The first parameter of `writestr` is filename. Please refer to the [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/zipfile.html#zipfile.ZipFile.writestr) for details.

Comment: You should not use the `write` method because it expects an actual file on the disk, and you only have the file content in the memory.

Comment: Will try this. Thank you. I'm overwhelmed by the docs but will read further coming from your answer.

Answer (score 0):

Since you are using PyFilesystem, you can open a S3 filesystem and a Zip filesystem, then use [copy_file](https://docs.pyfilesystem.org/en/latest/reference/copy.html#fs.copy.copy_file) to copy between them.

Something like the following should work:

```
import os
from fs import open_fs
from fs.copy import copy_file

with open_fs(os.getenv('s3_sample_folder')) as s3_fs:
    with open_fs('zip://zipfile.zip', create=True) as zip_fs:
        for filename in file_names():
            copy_file(s3_fs, filename, zip_fs, filename)
```